# Merging byte[] that was transfered through bluetooth

Tags: android, byte, android-bluetooth

So, I used [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) Android sample as a guide to make a bluetooth connection without any kind of validation (This app will have a very restrict userbase and will not be available to download at the store).

I was able to transfer string just fine, and it works like a charm. My problem is when trying to transfer images.

I have one activity that sends the byte[] of the image to the bluetooth service and a handler on the other activity that recieves the message and do wharever with the said message.

The thing is, because of the size of the buffer the handler receives parts of the original byte[]. What I'm tryng to do is to merge all the parts in one byte and save it.

This is the loop that I do inside my handler:

```
byte[] result = new byte[originalByteSize];
byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

if (cont < byteTimes){
    if (result == null) {
        result = appendData(readBuf,readBuf);
    } else {
        result = appendData(result,readBuf);         
    }
} else {
    new SavePhotoTask(cont).execute(result);
}
```

This is the appendData function

```
protected byte[] appendData(byte[] firstObject,byte[] secondObject){
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );
    try {
        if (firstObject!=null && firstObject.length!=0)
            outputStream.write(firstObject);
        if (secondObject!=null && secondObject.length!=0)
            outputStream.write(secondObject);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

And here is where I write the file:

```
    public class SavePhotoTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String> {

    int counter = 0;

    public SavePhotoTask(int cont){
        this.counter = cont;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(byte[]... jpeg) {
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), counter + "_photo.jpg");

        if (photo.exists()) {
            photo.delete();
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());

            fos.write(jpeg[0]);
            fos.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
        }

        return (null);
    }
```

What I needed is just a tip in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: So what is the problem in this code?

Comment: @pratt the image that outputs is just a black screen

Comment: Code looks fine, need to debug the code I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751797/bluetooth-connection-cant-send-strings-properly)

The problem was in the way I was writing and reading the stream.

```
public static void writeItem(OutputStream out, String s) throws IOException
{
    // Get the array of bytes for the string item:
    byte[] bs = s.getBytes(); // as bytes
    // Encapsulate by sending first the total length on 4 bytes :
    //   - bits 7..0 of length
    out.write(bs.length);      // modulo 256 done by write method
    //   - bits 15..8 of length
    out.write(bs.length>>>8);  // modulo 256 done by write method
    //   - bits 23..16 of length
    out.write(bs.length>>>16); // modulo 256 done by write method
    //   - bits 31..24 of length
    out.write(bs.length>>>24); // modulo 256 done by write method
    // Write the array content now:
    out.write(bs); // Send the bytes
    out.flush();
}

public static String readItem(InputStream in) throws IOException
{
    // first, read the total length on 4 bytes
    //  - if first byte is missing, end of stream reached
    int len = in.read(); // 1 byte
    if (len<0) throw new IOException("end of stream");
    //  - the other 3 bytes of length are mandatory
    for(int i=1;i<4;i++) // need 3 more bytes:
    {
        int n = in.read();
        if (n<0) throw new IOException("partial data");
        len |= n << (i<<3); // shift by 8,16,24
    }
    // Create the array to receive len bytes:
    byte[] bs = new byte[len];
    // Read the len bytes into the created array
    int ofs = 0;
    while (len>0) // while there is some byte to read
    {
        int n = in.read(bs, ofs, len); // number of bytes actually read
        if (n<0) throw new IOException("partial data");
        ofs += n; // update offset
        len -= n; // update remaining number of bytes to read
    }
    // Transform bytes into String item:
    return new String(bs);
}
```